# Bash split command to split line in comma separated values

Tags: bash, shell

I have a large file with 2000 hostnames and I want to create multiple files with 25 each host per file, but separated by a comma and the last `,` should be removed.

Large.txt:

```
host1
host2
host3
.
.
host10000
```

The below-split command is creating multiple files like `file1`, `file2` ... however, the host are not `,` separated and its not the expected output.

```
split -d -l 25 large.txt file
```

The expected output is:

```
host1,host2,host3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to perform 2 separate operations ... 1) `split` the file and 2) reformat the files generated by `split`.

The first step is already done:

```
split -d -l 25 large.txt file
```

For the second step let's work with the results that are dumped into the first file by the basic `split` command:

```
$ cat file00
host1
host2
host3
...
host25
```

We want to pull these lines into a single line using a comma (`,`) as delimiter.  For this example I'll use an `awk` solution:

```
$ cat file00 | awk '{ printf "%s%s", sep, $0 ; sep="," } END { print "" }'
host1,host2,host3...,host25
```

Where:

- `sep` is initially undefined (aka empty string)
- on each successive line processed by `awk` we set `sep` to a comma
- the `printf` doesn't include a linefeed (`\n`) so each successive `printf` will append to the 'first' line of output
- we `END` the script by printing a linefeed to the end of the file

It just so happens that `split` has an option to call a secondary script/code-snippet to allow for custom formatting of the output (generated by `split`); the option is `--filter`.  A few issues to keep in mind:

- the initial output from `split` is (effectively) piped as input to the command listed in the `--filter` option
- it is necessary to escape (with backslash) certain characters in the command (eg, double quotes, dollar sign) so as to keep them from being interpreted by the `split` command
- the `--filter` option automatically has access to the current `split` outfile name using the `$FILE` variable

Pulling everything together gives us:

```
$ split -d -l 25 --filter="awk '{ printf \"%s%s\", sep, \$0 ; sep=\",\" } END { print \"\" }' > \$FILE" large.txt file
$ cat file00
host1,host2,host3...,host25
```

Comment: really clever comma separation handling! I replaced the silly `if` with your solution in my "pure `awk`" answer. hope you don't mind :)

Comment: go for it!  I'm 'guilty' of picking up, and re-using, quite a few nuggets I've seen in code generated by others, too :-)

Answer (score 1):

Using the `--filter` option on GNU split:

```
split -d -l 25 --filter="(perl -ne 'chomp; print \",\" if \$i++; print'; echo) > \$FILE" large.txt file
```

Answer (score 1):

using `awk`:

```
awk '
BEGIN            { PREFIX = "file"; n = 0; }
                 { hosts = hosts sep $0; sep = ","; }
function flush() { print hosts > PREFIX n++; hosts = ""; sep = ""; }
NR % 25 == 0     { flush(); }
END              { flush(); }
' large.txt
```

edit: improved comma separation handling *stealing* from [markp-fuso's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62029444/13527856) :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use below mentioned bash code snippet

> INPUT FILE

```
~$ cat domainlist.txt
domain1.com
domain2.com
domain3.com
domain4.com
domain5.com
domain6.com
domain7.com
domain8.com
```

> Script

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

FILE_NAME=domainlist.txt
LIMIT=4
OUTPUT_PREFIX=domain_
CMD="csplit ${FILE_NAME} ${LIMIT} {1} -f ${OUTPUT_PREFIX}"
eval ${CMD}
#=====#
for file in ${OUTPUT_PREFIX}*; do
    echo $file
    sed -i ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/,/g' $file
done
```

> OUTPUT

```
./mysplit.sh 

36
48
12
domain_00
domain_01
domain_02
~$ cat domain_00
domain1.com,domain2.com,domain3.com
```

> Change LIMIT, OUTPUT_PREFIX file name prefix and input file as per your requirement